# How to scrape and visualize my facebook network using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, gephi

I want to do a graph analysis and visualize my facebook network, and I am looking for tutorials on how to get the data.  I saw this tutorial using Outwit Hub but I think Facebook has made it difficult to get the data using other sources.  Would appreciate some instructions using the API if that is even possible. Thanks.

Comment: The Facebook API only give you app friends and not all friends

Comment: A bit too late but netvizz is also useful